# Star rating plugin (set multiple attributes not working)

Tags: jquery, plugins, rating

I'm using the fyneworks plugin and it's driving me a little crazy.  I just want to set the ratings to readOnly and display the avg rating from my server.  I can do one or the other, but I can't manage to do both.  There's a demo on the site which shows an example of such functionality, but it doesn't display the code and I've had annoying time trying to look through their many js files.

```
$('.star').rating({readOnly:true, select:{{score}} });
```

I've tried various quoting iterations without any success.  I also tried to set disabled property on the html forms

What gives?

Comment: The value you give for the "select" value looks like a syntax error to me. What do you want "select" to be?  The value of the variable "score"?

Comment: yeah. score is a django context variable.

Comment: i'm sorry, I should have made that clear. django context syntax is {{context_variable}}

Comment: Where did you find a demo that shows the exact example?  That will help.  Also, have you verified that the django context variable is outputting what you're expecting?

Comment: the context is outputting correctly. The demo is here:http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/#tab-Testing.  It's the one with the readonly/default description. I'm having a tough time finding the applicable source

Comment: nobody has a clue on this one?